# Text to Html conversion in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 list of around 198 items. For the first 30 items **Text to Html** Javascript function successfully converts text code to Html but when I am trying to select next 31 items and go ahead using the pagination the function does not able to convert Html and display only text codes. Does anyone please who have the code handy to make this work? Below is the code used in SharePoint 2010. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function TextToHTML(NodeSet, HTMLregexp) {
var CellContent = "";
var i=0;
while (i < NodeSet.length){
try {
CellContent = NodeSet[i].innerText || NodeSet[i].textContent;
if (HTMLregexp.test(CellContent)) {NodeSet[i].innerHTML = CellContent;}
} 
catch(err){}
i=i+1;
}
}

// Calendar views
var regexpA = new RegExp("\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*");
TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("a"),regexpA);

// List views
var regexpTD = new RegExp("^\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*$");
TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),regexpTD);

// This function is call continuesly every 100ms until the length of the main field changes
// after which the convert text to HTML is executed.
//
var postElemLength = 0;
function PostConvertToHtml() 
{
     if (postElemLength == document.getElementsByTagName("TD").length)
     {
          setTimeout(PostConvertToHtml,100);
     }
     else
     {
          var regexpTD = new RegExp("^\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*$");
          TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),regexpTD);
     }
}

// Grouped list views
ExpGroupRenderData = (function (old) {
    return function (htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded) {

    var result = old(htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded);
    var regexpTD = new RegExp("^\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*$");
    TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),regexpTD);

    // start the periodic callback to check when the element has been changed
    if(isLoaded == 'false')
        {
        postElemLength = document.getElementsByTagName("TD").length;
        setTimeout(PostConvertToHtml,100);
        }
    };
})(ExpGroupRenderData);

// Preview pane views
if (typeof(showpreview1)=="function") {
showpreview1 = (function (old) {
    return function (o) {
    var result = old(o);
    var regexpTD = new RegExp("^\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*$");
    TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),regexpTD);
    };
})(showpreview1);
}</script>
```

Below is the generated text code which needs to be converted to Html. Thanks.

```
="<div style='position:relative;display:inline-block;width:100%;'>
    <div style='width:100%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;border:1px solid "&Project_Status_clr&";position:absolute;color:"&Project_Status_clr&";'> "&Project_Status&"
    </div>
    <div style='display:inline-block;width: 100%;background-color:"&Project_Status_clr&";text-align:center;border:1px solid;z-index:-1;filter:alpha(opacity=20);opacity:0.2;'>"&Project_Status&"
    </div>
</div>"
```

Comment: You might be performing more work than is necessary. Have you tried changing that calculated column to have a return type of "number" instead of (presumably) "string"? That's usually sufficient to render HTML.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your help. Really It works..

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When generating a string of HTML in a calculated column in SharePoint 2010, you can change the calculated column's value type to "Number" to get the HTML to render in the list view.

Comment: Hi there, I am most thankful to your above suggestion. Here I got stuck into my project once again. Kindly can you please suggest me how can I render text string code to HTML, when I click on next page using previous in Office 365. Apparently I used calculated column's value type to "Number" but still it shows me the same text string value.

Comment: In addition to above comments, I have used 5 calculated columns and around 2200 items for which I need to render it properly into HTML version. Thank you..

Comment: Hi Barun, I recommend asking a new question for the problem in Office 365, because the solution will likely be different than it was for SharePoint 2010.